# Handwriting Recognition Keyboard with Graffiti Support

Tags: android, keyboard

Call me nostalgic, old-fashioned, or whatever you might. But personally, I kind-of miss the time when I could write on my [Visor Prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handspring_%28company%29#Visor_Prism) and draw out nearly any letter, number, or symbol, with near-perfect accuracy, using just one or two strokes.

These days though, handwriting recognition apps seem to want you to actually write like you naturally would even though writing one letter at a time without shifting to the right after each letter is wholly unnatural. And, of course, because the app has to guess at your writing style, these things can be wildly inaccurate.

So, I'd personally be much more comfortable with a handwriting style keyboard that supports a simplified and standardized character set like the old [Graffiti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graffiti_%28Palm_OS%29) format.

[image]

Is there anything out there that does that for Android?

Platform: Samsung Galaxy S8+ running Android 7.0

Comment: Graffiti is by no way outdated. Once you learned the stenographic alphabet you can write quickly and flawlessly without looking at the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The only one existing to my knowledge is **[Graffiti Pro for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.access_company.graffiti_pro):**

[image: Graffiti] [image: Graffiti]
<sup>*Graffiti Pro for Android* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.access_company.graffiti_pro); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As the first screenshot shows, it supports about the same style as the *Palm Pilots* did/do, even the input area resembles that. The app description even refers to that:

> If you were a user of a PalmOS based PDA in the past, this will all be very familiar to you as the input method used by those devices was a stylus drawing Graffiti strokes in an input area at the bottom of the display.

I have not tried it myself, so I cannot say how well it works. It was last updated about a year ago, so I cannot say if it is still maintained either, or if it's fully supporting Android 7 (though I don't know why it should not).

Answer (score 0):

There is a free version of Graffiti: 'Graffiti for Android'. I have used this since the days of Palm Pilots, and on all my Android phones since.

Comment: Can you add a link?